# Insert Path of a file with \\ in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, file, path

I am making a standalone application using java,and in that i need to insert the path of the image that user chooses from file chooser.
I am getting the path of the file but when i store it in the database(mysql) it doesn't stores the `\`,so when i retrieve that path,the file doesn't show up.

How to store the path of file with `\\` so that one gets escaped using java code?

i tried using replaceall method but its giving an error of illegal character set.

```
filename.replaceall("\","\\");
```

But this didn't work out.

Comment: Are you going to use the stored path in another Java application, or is it used for something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Prepared statement to store path containing `\`.[`PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) doesn't escape anything

Answer (score 4):

Since `String` is immutable and all methods you call on it doesn't change `String`s internal value, but rather *return* the modified result, you need to assign the result of the replace to a variable. Also, since you want replace chars, not regex patterns, the [`replace()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method is more than sufficient. The [`replaceAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes regex and the `\` is a special character in regex as well.

```
filename = filename.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

However, forward slashes are supposed to work as good in Windows.

```
filename = filename.replace("\\", "/");
```

However #2, you might want to store it in DB using `PreparedStatement` which sanitizes bad and SQL-injection-sensitive characters for you away. [Prepare here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, why would you like to store the file path in a DB? This is prone to portability errors. I'd suggest to store only the (unique) filename and have the actual files in a single common path which is configureable as application setting.

Answer (score 0):

The slash should not be an issue.  Make sure your path has the slash before you insert into the database.   Also make sure you are using a PreparedStatement to insert the data.

Answer (score -1):

With respect to Your posts BalusC but I think I cannot agree with you in one thing. Indeed Strings are immutable but filename.replace("a","b") return new instance of string.

So I think assigning to new variable is not necessary?

Answer (score -1):

We can also use `addslashes` function for saving the file path,

```
addslashes($filepath)
```