# Storing path of file in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I read from a few sources that path of a file containing '\' can be stored in mysql table using Prepared statement.

I am using the following code.

```
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String myDB = "jdbc:odbc:proj";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myDB, "", "");
    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("insert into loads values ('"+dept.getSelectedItem()+"','"+linkpath.getText()+"')");
    st.execute();
```

where linkpath is the text box containing the path of the file.

However even after using this code the path is getting stored in mysql table without '\'.

Please suggest a solution for the same

Comment: You misuse `PreparedStatement`. Read the javadoc and tutorials on the net. This is not how you do it.

Comment: @fge Ya I know we can use place holders in prepared statements and we can insert the parameters afterwards but I have also read somewhere that prepared statement never escapes any character. So I was trying out this method

Comment: Don't believe _everything_ you read; have you at least tried?

Comment: Ya I tried this code and yet it is escaping the characters

Comment: I read it from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763243/insert-path-of-a-file-with-in-mysql-using-java?rq=1)